# How do I use a function return as a condition of an if else then shortcut?

Tags: bash, shell-script

There are instances where a function needs to execute and return to the caller and this works for me.

```
if tst; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "failure"
fi

function tst () {
    return 0;
}
```

However, I can't seem to be able to do it using shortcut syntax. I've tried many combinations of the following statement including testing if [[ tst = true ]] or if it = "0" but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
[[ tst ]] && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

What is the proper way to test the function in the if condition using bash shortcut syntax?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `A && B || C`, then simply call the function directly:

```
tst && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

If you want to use `[[`, you'd have to use the exit value:

```
tst
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then 
    ...
```

Comment: `$? == 0` Is that a good idea?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I think so. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: `==` is a pattern matching comparison. Arithmetic comparison is `-eq` (with `[[ ]]`, too). So technically it works but rather as a coincidence.

Comment: @HaukeLaging updated. But then again, I'd say if one is doing numeric comparison, `(())` should be used instead.

Comment: Possible, too, but I don't remember ever having seen that.

Comment: I would just like to say; `tst` on it's own then `$?` on the next line is very counter-intuitive if you don't already know why that is supposed to work.

Answer (score 7):

(this is not really an answer, more of a comment)

You have to be a bit careful about the `a && b || c` shortcuts:

- if `a` returns success, then `b` is executed
- if `b` subsequently returns an exit status, then `c` will be executed too.

```
$ [[ -f /etc/passwd ]] && { echo "file exists"; false; } || echo "file does not exist"
file exists
file does not exist
```

`if a; then b; else c; fi` is safer in this regard, in that `c` does not depend on `b`, only `a`

```
$ if [[ -f /etc/passwd ]];then { echo "file exists"; false; }; else echo "file does not exist"; fi
file exists
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: if `b` subsequently returns a *non-zero* exit status, then `c` will be executed too. But you can do this to prevent possibly unwanted execution of `c`: `a && { b; true; } || c` or `a && { b || true; } || c` which are basically turning around your demonstration.